# C++: Pure virtual destructor in abstract class with members

Tags: c++, destructor, pure-virtual, virtual-destructor

I've just started learning C++ and stumbled across this problem..
I've written this abstract class with pure virtual destructor:

```
#ifndef ANIMAL
#define ANIMAL
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Animal {
public:
    Animal();
    virtual ~Animal() = 0;
    Animal(string name, int age);
    virtual string says() = 0;
    void setName(string name);
    void setAge(int age);
    string getName() const;
    int getAge() const;

private:
    int _age;
    string _name;
};
inline Animal::~Animal() { }
```

Created dynamically and destroyed like this...

```
Animal** animalArray = new  Animal*[10];
animalArray[0] = new Dog(name, age);
animalArray[1] = new Cat(name, age);
animalArray[2] = new Owl(name, age);

delete[] animalArray;
```

and I am left wondering if an Animal object is created dynamically and then destroyed, will the _age and _name members get destroyed properly since the destructor for Animal class is empty? If so, why?

Thanks :D

Comment: However, in your code, all animals are not destroyed.  You have `new`-ed them but haven't done any `delete`

Comment: and, in fact your question has nothing to do with virtual destructor.  You are simply wondering how an ordinary dtor works

Comment: As someone who has just started learning C++, you are probably much better off with `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Animal>>`. And never `use namespace` in a header in the global scope.

Comment: @AdrianShum I see, the reason I think it "might" be something to do with virtual destructor is because I've declared `inline Animal::~Animal() { }` and it being empty worries me

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the tip! Didn't really know how to create abstract type array and that's the first solution I found on the net... so I used it.. :( and so... if not using `use namespace`.. `std::string` for each string will be fine??

Comment: Yes I actually prefer `std::string` everywhere, but `using std::string` is also an option.

Comment: A simple rule of thumb: Don't do `using/using namespace` in Headers.  Always use the full name in header.  This will avoid namespace pollution.  It is fine to use `using/using namespace` in the impl file though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example you posted, you're actually not destroying everything correctly.  In the line

```
delete[] animalArray;
```

you are deleting an array of `Animal*`s.  Note that *this does not automatically destroy the things being pointed to!*  You would have to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    delete animalArray[i];
delete[] animalArray;
```

This destroys each element, *then* destroys the container.

Now, your actual question is asking whether the private member variables are going to be cleanly destroyed.  The answer is yes--after your destructor runs, any *statically allocated* variables' destructors will also be called by the compiler.  It is their obligation to clean up after themselves.  When you're doing polymorphism as in your example, the (empty) destructor `Animal::~Animal` will indeed be called.

Note that this carries the same warning as the code above:  if you instead have

```
string* _name;
```

that you dynamically allocate in the constructor (with `new`), then the `string*` will be destroyed, but the *pointed to* `string` will not be.  So in that case, you would have to manually call `delete` to properly clean up.

Comment: Cool! that explains a lot. Thank you :D

Comment: Sure thing!  One tool you might want to look at regarding leaks performance testing is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).  It will let you know if you're leaking memory.

Answer (score 0):

it will , destructor is not really destroy the object you created , it is called before the object being destroied, if you have not new something in constructor , there is no need for you to delete it.

I try to finger out a sample to prove

when using string(with a pointer member) object as member variable, its destructor will be called, even we do nothing in the class's destructor

so I tried to used a user-defined String as object, so it is easy for us to write some log in the destructor.

it outputs:

```
constructor is called
constructor is called
constructor is called
operator constructor is called
destructor is called
operator constructor is called
destructor is called
virtual ~Dog()
virtual ~Animal()
destructor is called
```

it show is when  virtual ~Animal() is called , the string object'destructor in the Animal class is called.

we can change  the string object to string*(using new in construtor) while still doing nothing in the destructor , and we will see the string's destructor is not called

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


class String{
public:
    String(const char *str = NULL);
    String(const String &str);
    ~String();
    String operator+(const String & str);
    String & operator=(const String &str);
    bool operator==(const String &str);
    int Length();
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &o,const String &str);
    String SubStr(int start, int end);
private:
    char * charArray;
};

String::String(const char *str)
{
    if(str == NULL){
        charArray=new char[1];
        charArray[0]='\0';
    }else{
        charArray=new char[strlen(str)+1];
        strcpy(charArray,str);
    }
    std::cout<< "constructor is called" << std::endl;
}
String::String(const String &str)
{
    std::cout<< "constructor is called" << std::endl;
    charArray = new char[strlen(str.charArray)+1];
    strcpy(charArray,str.charArray);
}
String::~String()
{
    std::cout<< "destructor is called" << std::endl;
    delete [] charArray;
}
String String::operator+(const String &str)
{
    String res;
    delete [] res.charArray;
    res.charArray = new char[strlen(charArray)+strlen(str.charArray)+1];
    strcpy(res.charArray,charArray);
    strcpy(res.charArray+strlen(charArray),str.charArray);
    return res;
}
String & String::operator=(const String &str)
{
    if(charArray == str.charArray)
        return *this;
    delete [] charArray;
    charArray = new char[strlen(str.charArray)+1];
    strcpy(charArray,str.charArray);
    std::cout<< "operator constructor is called" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
bool String::operator==(const String &str)
{
    return strcmp(charArray,str.charArray) == 0;
}
int String::Length()
{
    return strlen(charArray);
}
ostream & operator<<(ostream &o, const String &str)
{
    o<<str.charArray;
    return o;
}

String String::SubStr(int start, int end)
{
    String res;
    delete [] res.charArray;
    res.charArray = new char[end-start+1];
    for(int i=0; i+start<end; i++){
        res.charArray[i]=charArray[start+i];
    }
    res.charArray[end-start] = '\0';
    return res;
}


class Animal {
public:
    Animal();
    virtual ~Animal()=0;
    Animal(String name, int age);

public:
    int _age;
    String _name;
};
Animal::~Animal(){
    std::cout << "Animal::~Animal()" << std::endl;
}
Animal::Animal(String name, int age)
{
    this->_name = name;
    this->_age = age;
}

class Dog :public Animal
{
public:
    virtual ~Dog() {
         std::cout << "virtual ~Dog()" << std::endl;
    };
    Dog(String name, int age):Animal(name,age)
    {
        this->_name = name;
        this->_age = age;
    }
};

int main(){
   Animal* p = new Dog( String("dog"),1);
   delete p;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `string` object probably has a pointer inside, so it's important for its destructor to be called.

Comment: Note that in his example no destructors are called since he doesn't `delete` the elements of `animalArray`.

Comment: @MarkRansom string object is member variable of the class , its destructor will be called.

Answer (score 0):

yes they will. By making the Animal destructor virtual (or pure virtual in your case, doesn't matter regarding your question) you make sure that everything is properly destroyed when using Animal as a base class.

The destructor of Animal will call the destructor for each of it's members in reverse initialization order (i.e. it will destroy _name first and _age afterwards) and thereby makes sure that everything is properly freed.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/031.htm) you cannot instantiate a class with a pure virtual destructor unless it also has a body. The reason is that any derived class will need to call that destructor after its own destructor is finished.

We can verify this with at least one compiler: http://ideone.com/KcwL8W

```
#include <string>

class Animal
{
    public:
    virtual ~Animal() = 0;

    std::string _name;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
};

int main() {
    Animal* pet = new Dog;
    delete pet;
    return 0;
}

/home/abDVbj/cc8ghrZk.o: In function `Dog::~Dog()':
prog.cpp:(.text._ZN3DogD2Ev[_ZN3DogD5Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to `Animal::~Animal()'
/home/abDVbj/cc8ghrZk.o: In function `Dog::~Dog()':
prog.cpp:(.text._ZN3DogD0Ev[_ZN3DogD0Ev]+0x12): undefined reference to `Animal::~Animal()'
```

Comment: but if you define the pure virtual function , it will be ok Animal::~Animal(){}

Comment: @michaeltang, ah yes I missed that in the question. Thanks.